# Store data across viewers

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown that every 30 seconds restarts the countdown.

```
    var interval = 31000;

    function reset() {
localStorage.endTime = +new Date + interval;
    }

    if( ! localStorage.endTime ) {
reset();
    }

    setInterval( function() {
var remaining = localStorage.endTime - new Date;
if( remaining >= 0 ) {
    $('#timer').text( Math.floor( remaining / 1000 ) );
} else {
    reset();
}
    }, 100 );
```

I need to find a way to countdown across the whole server. So every viewer will experience the same countdown. Any ideas?

Comment: Set the value from the server-side. Either send it through AJAX or print it directly during the server side rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that code in [IIF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) in separate js file and inslude it on every page of your site and it should work cause local storage variables are available in every page in you site.

```
(function(){ /*... your code ...*/ })();
```

If you want to implement it on server side, so you can do it same way but instead of only setting value in local variable you also have to post it on server and retrieve when IIF invokes for first time (using AJAX).

```
(function(){ /*get variable end time and 
   in callback set it to local storage ... your code ... 
   in reset function post new value of end time on server */  
})();
```